# Spark - Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I just started playing with Spark and I'm already struggling. I just downloaded Spark's `spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.4` and tried to open PySpark Shell `./bin/pyspark` but I was unfortunately prompted the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
```

environment:

- Ubuntu 14.04.4 64-Bit
- Java version "1.8.0_77"
- Python 2.7.6
- Spark 1.6.1 Pre-build for Hadoop 2.4 and later

Any clues how to troubleshoot this?

**It works fine with Spark 1.2.0 Pre-build for Hadoop 2.4 and later**

Answer (score -1):

please check whether the java is installed on the machine
and check all the jar files under lib directory are working